# Excel not rendering CSS correctly for imported web table

Tags: html, css, excel, vba

I'm trying to import a web table (with some CSS formatting) into excel; however, Excel refuses to render it properly. Here is my HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <style type="text/css">
            table { table-layout:auto; border-collapse:collapse; border:thin solid black; font-family:Arial; }
            th { } 
            .Headline { padding:0pt; font-size:9pt; background-color:#FFFF00; color:#FF0000; border:thin solid black; vertical-align:top; }
            tbody { border:1px solid Black; }
            tbody:nth-child(odd) { background: RGB(255, 255, 220); }
            tbody:nth-child(even) { background: RGB(238, 255, 255); }           
            td { vertical-align:top; border:thin dotted Silver; padding:0pt; font-size:8pt; padding-right:3px; padding-left:3px; mso-number-format:"\@"; }
            pre { margin:0; padding:0; white-space:pre-wrap; font-size:8pt; font-family:Arial; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <th class="Headline">TC #</th>
            <th class="Headline">Steps</th>
            <th class="Headline">Details</th>
            <th class="Headline">Timestamp</th>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="UCNumber">1</td>
                    <td class="Level1">▬▬ UC_010 ▬▬</td>
                    <td><pre>Product Multiple; Event = NEW</pre></td>
                    <td>01/04/2015 - 10:43:54</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td class="Level1">●●● TD_SETUP</td>
                    <td><pre>Executing script steps of TD_SETUP</pre></td>
                    <td>01/04/2015 - 10:43:54</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td class="Level1">Statement Skipped: #NEWAMEND</td>
                    <td><pre>0</pre>
                    </td>
                    <td>01/04/2015 - 10:43:55</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td class="Level1">Statement Skipped: #OUTBOUND</td>
                    <td><pre>2</pre>
                    </td>
                    <td>01/04/2015 - 10:43:55</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td class="Level1">●●● TD_VERIFYNEWAMEND</td>
                    <td><pre>Executing script steps of TD_VERIFYNEWAMEND</pre></td>
                    <td>01/04/2015 - 10:44:01</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="UCNumber">2</td>
                    <td class="Level1">▬▬ UC_011 ▬▬</td>
                    <td><pre>Product Multiple; Event = AMEND</pre></td>
                    <td>01/04/2015 - 10:45:14</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td class="Level1">●●● TD_SETUP</td>
                    <td><pre>Executing script steps of TD_SETUP</pre></td>
                    <td>01/04/2015 - 10:45:14</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td class="Level1">Statement Skipped: #NEWAMEND</td>
                    <td><pre>0</pre></td>
                    <td>01/04/2015 - 10:45:14</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td class="Level1">Statement Skipped: #OUTBOUND</td>
                    <td><pre>2</pre></td>
                    <td>01/04/2015 - 10:45:14</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td class="Level1">●●● TD_VERIFYNEWAMEND</td>
                    <td><pre>Executing script steps of TD_VERIFYNEWAMEND</pre></td>
                    <td>01/04/2015 - 10:45:20</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="UCNumber">3</td>
                    <td class="Level1">▬▬ UC012 ▬▬</td>
                    <td><pre>Product Multiple; Event = CANCEL</pre></td>
                    <td>01/04/2015 - 10:46:34</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td class="Level1">●●● TD_SETUP</td>
                    <td><pre>Executing script steps of TD_SETUP</pre></td>
                    <td>01/04/2015 - 10:46:34</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td class="Level1">Statement Skipped: #CANCEL</td>
                    <td><pre>3</pre></td>
                    <td>01/04/2015 - 10:46:34</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td class="Level1">●●● TD_VERIFYCANCEL</td>
                    <td><pre>Executing script steps of TD_VERIFYCANCEL</pre></td>
                    <td>01/04/2015 - 10:46:40</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Browser displays it as

[image]
However, when I import it in Excel it is showing up as follows

[image]

Excel VBA

```
conStr = "URL;file:///" & curResDir & "\Results.html"
With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=conStr, Destination:=Range("A1"))
    .Name = "QTPResult"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = False
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingAll
    .WebTables = "1"
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = True
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = True
    .WebDisableRedirections = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

Comment: Excel is not a web browser. Does it have the concept of CSS?

Comment: I'm with MatthewD, Excel is not a web browser. But could ".PreserveFormatting = False" have anything to do with it?

Comment: @MatthewD - Looks like Excel pick and choose which CSS it want to render. I want to know how to make sure it renders all the formats.

Comment: @n8wrl - Even with `PreserveFormatting = True`,the result is same.